# how to use greaterThan in XML, like <if> <Then>

Tags: xml, ant, ant-contrib

when i am using

```
    <if>        
        <equals arg1="10" arg2="${getValue}"/>
        <then>  
            <fail message="value is not equal to 10 "/>
        </then>
    </if>
```

it is working fine.

but when i am trying to use like

```
    <if>        
        <greaterThan arg1="10" arg2="${getValue}"/>
        <then>  
            <fail message="value is greaterThan 10 "/>
        </then>
    </if>
```

it is giving below error

> if doesn't support the nested "greaterThan" element.

Comment: Not supported with if/condtionals : http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/more_conditions.html